# Only allow updating JPA entity when @version attribute matches

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, version, one-to-many

I have two classes, a file and an attachment. There is a version attribute on the file and it has a onetomany relationship. I have written code to upload/add attachments to the file. The code works.

However, It doesn't look at the version attribute of 'File' and updates the entity anyway. I would like to add versioning to be checked when calling the addAttachment method. I've tried providing the current value as a requestparam and set it on the File, however, this is not being checked. Any advice on how to setup the controller to make versioning work?

Classes:

```
....    
@Data
public class File {
    @Id
    private Long fileId;
    @Version
    private Long tstamp;
    @OneToMany(cascase = CascadeType.All)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fileId", referencedColumnName = "fileId")
    private List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    
    ....
    
    public void addAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
        attachments.add(attachment);
    }
}

@Data
public class Attachment {
    @Id
    private Long attachmentId;
    private String ....;
    
    ......
}
```

FileService to add attachment to file:

```
@Transactional
public File addAttachmentToFile(Long id, Long tstamp, Long attachmentId) {
    File fileCurrent = getFileById(id);
    fileCurrent.setTstamp(tstamp);
    Attachment attachment = attachmentService.getAttachmentById(attachmentId);

    fileCurrent.addAttachment(attachment);
    File file = saveFile(fileCurrent);
    return file;
}
```

File controller:

```
@PostMapping("/{fileId}/attachments")
public ResponseEntity<File> addAttachmentToFile(@PathVariable final Long fileId, @RequestParam("version") Long tstamp, @RequestParam("attachments") MultipartFile attachment) {
    Attachment createdAttachment = attachmentService.saveAttachment(attachment);
    Long attachmentId = createdAttachment.getAttachmentId();
    fileService.addAttachmentToFile(finDocId, tstamp, attachmentId);
    File file = fileService.getFileById(fileId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(file, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Which `@Version` did you import? `javax.persistence.Version` or the Spring one?

Comment: Also, does it get updated when other fields of the File are changed? What is the initial value of the version column when you add a new entity?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that:

> By default, the child or to-many relationship site owns the one-to-many association. Therefore, Hibernate doesn’t increment the version number of the parent entity when you add or remove a child entity.

But you can use the `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` to trigger the version update programmatically.

You can choose between 2 options to set the LockModeType for a specific entity. You either call the `lock` method on the EntityManager or perform a JPQL query and provide the `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` to the `setLockMode` method.

You could refer to [Hibernate Tips: How to Increase the Version of the Parent Entity When Updating a Child Entity](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-increase-version-parent-entity-updating-child-entity/) for the in-detail tutorial.

There's one more way you could try to achieve version update i.e. using Event Listeners. It also intercepts any child entity modification and acquires an `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` event on the associated root entity.

I think this method might be an optimal solution. You can follow [How to increment the parent entity version whenever a child entity gets modified with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) for the in-detail tutorial.

One more comment: I notice that you've set `tstamp` as version but I don't think the version is actually set as timestamps. They're usually like auto-increment that just increment by 1.

Comment: The version is updated when an attachment is added to the file. So the parent version is increased when a child is added. However, there is no logic in place to check the version from the functioncaller perspective. My question is how to implement this logic as I can't upload the File including current version in the requestbody and the attachments in the RequestParams simultaniously. Any advice is welcome

Comment: So you meant to say that you want to access the current version of the File.

Comment: Yes I want to check whether a provided version matches the version of the File, only than, the attachment is allowed to be added. I've edited the question with my next approach. However, this doesn't solve.